# DAG Implementation in Python

Tags: python, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

```
def get_Indegree_Of_Vertices(self):
    for ele in self.graph.keys():
        self.indegree[ele] = 0
        for i in self.graph.values():
            self.indegree[ele] += i.count(ele)
    return self.indegree

def DAG(self, root):
    # Queue is where I store all the nodes that have in-degree of zero
    queue = deque([root])
    x = queue.popleft()
    print(x)
    for neighbour in self.graph[x]:
        self.indegree[neighbour] -= 1 
        queue.append(neighbour)
        if self.indegree[neighbour] == 0:
            self.DAG(neighbour)
```

> Here, my approach is to first find all the vertices that have an in-degree Zero
>   Then find the in-degree of each of vertices
>   As you traverse you can deduce the degree of each vertex. If the in-degree is zero then do the recursion
>   HERE, self.indegree and self.graph are dictionary representations.
>   I don't know if my way of solving the problem is optimal but I just want to solve the problem this way. 
>   Also if there's some improvisation that'id be welcomed!!
>
> Also I don't why i"m getting this ERROR
>    unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'list' and 'int'

Comment: first of all, your implementation reads like it is a part of a class, but incomplete. Second, try print(type(self.indegree[neighbour])). according to your traceback this should be a list. Trying to add an integer to a list will give that error. Then, what is it that you want this line of code to do>

Comment: the problem is that `self.indegree[neighbour]` returns a list

Comment: Yes, it was a type error and I made a correction though at the same line I'm getting a keyError 5. What I want that line of code to do is reduce the indegree of the neighbor 
by 1.

Comment: At the initial level, I'm choosing a vertex for DFS traversal. As the graph traverses it'll reduce  the in-degree of next neighbor by 1 and if the neighbor has an in-degree of ZERO there'll a recursion

Answer (score 0):

[py-dag](https://github.com/thieman/py-dag/blob/master/dag/__init__.py) has a readable implementation, but it's pretty buggy.

The [networkx](https://github.com/networkx/networkx) DAG code is a lot more complete, but hard to understand.  Here's a couple of simple nextworkx DAG [examples](https://mungingdata.com/python/dag-directed-acyclic-graph-networkx/).

If you're implementing a DAG in production code, it's probably best to depend on networkx.  If you'd like to learn how to implement a DAG in Python, check out the networkx source code.